# Custom shell stops working after dup2

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a function to my shell where I need to redirect output to file. For example user write: `ls -l >> file` and `ls -l` should be written to file. Almost all things are correct but after first calling my function program stop and I can't write anything else. Below I present my function and I would appreciate any clues to resolve the problem:

```
void execute2(char *command, char **argv, char **argv2)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
    {     
        printf("*** ERROR ***\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) 
    {      
        close(1);    
        parse(command, argv, argv2);
        int output = open(*argv2, O_APPEND | O_WRONLY);
        dup2(output,1);      
        if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0) 
            exit(0);       
        if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) 
        {    
            printf("*** ERROR ***\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(output); 
    }
    else 
    {                                  
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
    }
}
```

`command` is command getting from user, `argv` is part of instruction and parameters and `argv2` is the output file.

Comment: You should `close(output)` after `dup2(output, 1)` and before the `execvp()` — preferably before the `strcmp()` too.  There's no need to test the return value from `execvp()`; it only returns if it fails.

Comment: If you miss the child dying somehow, your wait loop spins forever.  For debugging, capture and print the process ID and status.  For robustness; use `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1 && corpse != pid) printf("Child %d exited with status 0x.4X\n", corpse, status);`.  Even this isn't perfect; it ignores the possibility of a signal being handled and `wait()` returning `-1` with `errno == EINTR`.  At least this way, you'll know what's going on.

Comment: What command are you calling?   If you are invoking `ls` it appears that this ought to return.  If you are invoking `cat` or anything else that is going to block on a read from stdin, I would expect it to run until you send it a signal.

Comment: In both situation result is that same

Comment: I checked this and I think it doesn 't resolve problem. I suggest that when I call first time execute2 it works as well as I want but I never finish that proces. Or I don 't undestand something

Answer (score -2):

@Jonathan Leffler I checked this and I think it doesn 't resolve problem. I suggest that when I call first time execute2 it works as well as I want but I never finish that proces. Or I don 't undestand something

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)